# Load multiple URN in a same Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

How to load multiple URN or and array of URN in a viewer
and also use the GlobalOffest of the 1st URN to load the 2nd URN in same viewer

Answer (score 5):

It's simple, the basic scenario is from this official [blog's](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/model-aggregation-with-view-data-api-exposed.html) loadModel function.

You can load 2nd model while `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` was fired and apply 1st model's GlobalOffest to the 2nd model in my experience. Here is the example for this case:

```
 function _onGeometryLoaded( event ) {
   if( urns.length <= 0 ) {
       viewer.removeEventListener(
         Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
         _onGeometryLoaded
       );
       return;
   }

   viewer.loadModel( urns[0], { globalOffset: event.model.getData().globalOffset } );
   urns.splice( 0, 1 );
 }

 viewer.addEventListener(
   Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
   _onGeometryLoaded
 );

 viewer.loadModel( urns[0] );
 urns.splice( 0, 1 );
```

If you use `viewer.start()` to load the first model on the viewer initialization, those codes will be changed into:

```
 function _onGeometryLoaded( event ) {
   if( urns.length <= 0 ) {
       viewer.removeEventListener(
         Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
         _onGeometryLoaded
       );
       return;
   }

   viewer.loadModel( urns[0], { globalOffset: event.model.getData().globalOffset } );
   urns.splice( 0, 1 );
 }

 viewer.addEventListener(
   Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
   _onGeometryLoaded
 );

 // Change here
 viewer.start( urns[0], options, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback );
 urns.splice( 0, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That helps me a lot.
Now, it's event.model.getData().globalOffset to get the globalOffset.